# Class name of an EJB

Tags: java, ejb

I have some code along the lines of this:

```
@EJB
protected SomeService service;

// Somewhere in a method
service.getClass().getSimpleName();
```

What I was looking for was the name of the EJB class, which in this case should have been something along the lines of `SomeServiceBean`. What I get instead, however, is for example `$Proxy2128`.

Is there a way I can get the name of the actual EJB class that I implemented, instead of the proxy class?

*Think we're using ejb 3.0 with geronimo or something like that.*

Comment: I don't think it's possible, because it shouldn't be. Why do you want this class name?

Comment: If you're interested in this kind of information, it may be better to create 2 different interfaces, implemented by one bean. Then you can distinguish based on the different interfaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably not a good idea to do this. I suspect you are better off doing something like adding a method to the bean which returns a type string that is under your control. The simplest such implementation

```
public String getSimpleClassName() {
    return getClass().getSimpleName();
}
```

That is safe in the face proxying. It is not safe in the face of dynamic subclassing, but i don't know of any EJB implementations that do that (although there are certainly JPA implementations which do that).

A slightly more complicated, but fundamentally more straightforward, implementation would be to define:

```
public abstract String getSimpleClassName();
```

in a base class (or interface), and then writing:

```
public String getSimpleClassName() {
    return SomeService.class.getSimpleName();
}
```

In SomeService. That is cast-iron guaranteed to work.

Alternatively, if you are working with no-interface views, and don't mind reflection, and the risk of your system bursting into flames at any moment, then in the calling code, you can do:

```
private String findBeanClassName(Object beanRef) {
    return findBeanClass(beanRef).getSimpleName();
}

private Class<?> findBeanClass(Object beanRef) {
    return findAncestorWithAnnotation(beanRef.getClass(), Stateless.class);
}

private Class<?> findAncestorWithAnnotation(Class<?> cl, Class<? extends Annotation> annotation) {
    while ((cl != null) && !cl.isAnnotationPresent(annotation)) {
        cl = cl.getSuperclass();
    }
    return cl;
}
```

That ought to work. Obviously, you'd need to use a different annotation class if you are using a stateful bean.

Comment: Yeah, I ended up doing something like the last one. I just use it for a kind of logging, to see what was used to perform a certain action.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that this works for your case, but I faced a similar situation in which I had an interceptor to automatically logs the method invocation and I needed to log the full class name, but by using `getClass().getName()` the proxy's class name is printed. Instead of that, I used `getClass().getSuperclass().getName()`, to get the original class name.